# Help determinating the force equation for this circular motion problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, centripetal-force

[image]

Let's talk about the object B.(using cordinate system [image] but unit vector θ is 0 so I'll ignore that).

So on one side I think the force equation for B is :

[image: img]

Because I think when the radius is also changing, the radial acceleration isn't always negative, it could be positive or negative depending on the radius change [image: [insert r two dots].]

However, maybe because the Tension T is always towards the center, so does the acceleration and therefore the acceleration is always negative? Then the equation is actually :

[image: [long equation]]

But in the case that the mass B moves away from the center, the acceleration is positive but the tension is negative, which contradicts last equation.

Which one of the  statments is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you've written in equations is fine but you have prematurely tried to draw a conclusion. The force resolution on one side will not give you an answer.
The masses are connected (they cannot separate and as they are on opposite sides centripetal force prevents them approaching). Tension cancels out. Resolve the centripetal forces on both to establish the overall force.

$$F=(m_Ar_a-m_B(l-r_a))\omega^2$$

$$\ddot{r}=F/(m_A+m_B)$$

Answer (score 0):

Do two free body diagrams along the $\hat{r}$ direction. Consider  the distances from the center of rotation as $r_A$ and $r_B$ such that

$$r_A + r_B = \ell$$ and also

$$\ddot{r}_A + \ddot{r}_B = 0 $$

The two equations of motion are derived from the fact that without the tension the radial acceleration should be of the $r \omega^2$ form, and that a positive tension *reduces* the radial acceleration.

$$\begin{align} 
  m_A\, r_A\, \omega^2 -T & = m_A\, \ddot{r}_A \\
  m_B\, r_B\, \omega^2 -T & = m_B\, \ddot{r}_B
\end{align}$$

The above two equations are solved for the tension $T$ and for the radial accelerations $\ddot{r}_A = -\ddot{r}_B$.

I got

$$\boxed{ T = \frac{\ell \omega^2}{\frac{1}{m_A} + \frac{1}{m_B}} } $$

and thus $\ddot{r}_A = r_A \, \omega^2 - \frac{T}{m_A}$. You can check the result if you place the combined center of mass $\frac{r_A m_A-r_B m_B}{m_A+m_B}=0$ at the rotation center. This makes $\ddot{r}_A=0$ which makes intuitive sense as the system is *in balance*.

Comment: I'm confused about the statement that the tension reduces the radial acceleration,  I agree with r¨A+r¨B=0. But if we talk along the r^ direction the tension is towards the center of the rotation which is negative r^ and so does the acceleration rw^2.

Comment: A drawing to show what I mean : http://imgur.com/a/4I9E3

Comment: In cartesian coordinates $\ddot{x}=0$ without tension. The same statement in polar coordinates becomes $\ddot{r} = r \omega^2$ as the mass has to increase the radial distance to keep moving in a straight line. The tension makes the part move in a curve and hence $\ddot{r} < r \omega^2$ when tension is present.